# Посоветуйте пожалуйста плагины

Tags: html, jquery, css, вёрстка, hover

Посоветуйте пожалуйста плагины с таким hover-эффектом [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: filter grayscale

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7273927/image-greyscale-with-css-re-color-on-mouse-over

Answer (score 7, accepted):

По слову «плагины» можно догадаться, что у вас есть привычка решать задачи при помощи jquery-плагинов, но почти всегда проще обратить внимание на штуки, которые описаны в стандарте — CSS-фильтры, например.

```css
figure {
  margin: 0;
}

.gallery {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.gallery__item {
  flex-basis: calc(100% / 3);
  filter: grayscale(1);
  transition: filter .3s;
}

img {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.gallery__item:hover {
  transition: none;
  filter: grayscale(0);
}
```

```html
<section class="gallery">
  <figure class="gallery__item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/1" />
  </figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/2" />
  </figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/3" />
  </figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/4" />
  </figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/5" />
  </figure>
  <figure class="gallery__item">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/200/200/abstract/6" />
  </figure>
</section>
```